# Assign scroll animation to focus in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have the following code which focuses on an input field which has a validation error. I would like to add some sort of animation with the scroll to the focused position (so if you click submit it "scrolls up to where the first input field is which failed validation).

Any ideas?

```
 if(validation_failed == true) {
      $(selected_form).find(":input.validator_element_error:visible:enabled").first().focus();
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: I could just write this for you because I know exactly how to do it, but I'll forego the possible rep and ask what you have tried so far.  What have you tried?

Comment: @ExplosionPills : I have tried .scollTop() and also .animate() - I have never really used jquery's animated before and figured this would be a good start :) I also tried Google "Apply animation to jquery focus()" without much success :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can animate the scrollTop prior to applying focus. This is simplified from your example.

```
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $('input').offset().top}, 200, function() {
    $('input').focus();
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GdcUK/1/)

In your specific case, I would image you would just need to select the errored input element the way you wish and then replace `$('input')` in the above code with your selected element.

```
var errorInput = $(selected_form).find(":input.validator_element_error:visible:enabled").first();
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: errorInput.offset().top}, 200, function() {
    errorInput.focus();
});
```

Comment: this is focusing to the bottom of that div.